# Set and clear bits in a byte array in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I want to create a byte array (it can be fixed size) and set/clear specific bits inside this array given the position of the bits

For example we have a byte array of length 16 (128bits). And I want to set the bit no 100, 110, 16, and 34.

Can I do that without math or logic operations? Like using any library or function?

Comment: The math or logic operations required are so simple that nobody dare to write a function or library for that. Also, you should know that in Python, integers have infinite length. So you do not need an array to store 128 bits.

Comment: @dskrypa Looks interesting! Thanks

Comment: @user3435121 I did not know that! Thanks! Seems like my problem is solved.